# Facebook API Python

Tags: python, api, facebook

Pessoal é possível listar TODOS os grupos de um amigo no face? Tipo mostrar os grupos que ele está?

Achei esse código mas não é o que eu quero, só mostra os amigos:

```
import urllib2
import json
url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=TOKEN'
resp = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
data = json.loads(resp.decode('utf-8'))
for amigo in data['data']:
   print (amigo['name'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tentou substituir friends por groups na url?
Lembrando que para acessar estas informações, o usuário deve autorizar o acesso. 
Na configuração da sua app, você deve acessar as permissões e cadastrar que está solicitando os grupos do usuário:

Mais informações:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/groups/

Para trabalhar com o facebook, você também pode utilizar o facepy:

```
pip install facepy
```

Fica bem mais simples para pegar as informações do usuário:

```
from facepy import GraphAPI

graph = GraphAPI('token_usuario')
data = graph.get('me?fields=id,email,name')
#data {u'id': u'11111111', u'name': u'Puam Dias'}
```